# ngOnInit or ngOnChanges not called while manually calling changeDetect() on a component

Tags: angular5

I have 3 component out of which p1 is parent and c1 and c2 is child ,

in c2 i am triggering the change detection by calling

> this.changeDetecionRef.detectChanges()

But this will not triggered . no ngOnChanges or ngOnInit function get called of Parent and child component.

Does I have to update any property i.e binding data from parent to child or child to parent .

Answer (score 0):

ngOnChanges is called only when the data-bound property was changed.
ngOnInit() is called, After all of the injected dependencies resolved. (It should call after ngOnChanges())

binding data from parent to child component,

parent.component.ts

```
  @Component({
selector:'parent-component',
template:`
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <button (click)="changeCount()">Change</button>
    <child-component [count]=Counter></child-component>`,
})

export class ParentComponent{
    Counter=2;

    changeCount(){
        this.Counter++;
    }
}
```

child.component.ts

```
    @Component({
    selector:'child-component',
    template:`<h2>Total Count {{count}}</h2>`
})

export class ChildComponent{
    @Input() count:number;
}
```

detectchanges() method should be called after updating the property,
for example,

```
 export class ParentComponent{
    Counter=2;

    changeCount(){
        this.Counter++;
        this.changeDetecionRef.detectChanges();
    }
}
```